# How to connect to a azure private storage account from a public azure static web app

Tags: azure, azure-storage-account, azure-static-web-app

I have a azure storage account with restricted access to VNet and there is a requirement to connect to it from a public facing azure static web app.

Is there any way to achieve this, I have already tried private endpoint for the static web app but that does not help as it makes my public app private and also my app is behind a front door and it does not support private endpoint for static web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible at this point in time. As you rightly mentioned, Private Endpoints won't help with your issue.
You would need [VNet Integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-vnet-integration) functionality so that Service Endpoints (not Private Endpoints - [see here for the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73769449/azure-difference-between-service-endpoint-and-private-endpoint-in-simple-terms/73769731#73769731)) can be leveraged but Azure Static Web Apps do not support this right now.
See [this GitHub Issue](https://%20https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/1021) for a similar request.

If using Service Endpoints is hard requirement, then leveraging an App Service Plan with a  traditional App Service might be an option but that would also have a potentially significant impact on costs.